# laravel blade showing curly brackets

Tags: php, laravel, object, laravel-blade

Here's my controller code:

```php
public function getIndex()
{

    \Eloquent::unguard();

     $users = \DB::table('users')->get();;

     return \View::make('index')->with('users', $users);

}
```

So nothing fancy whatsoever.

In my view I am displaying the data from the users table:

```php
@foreach ($users as $user) {
    {{$user->email}}
}      
@endforeach
```

But it seems that all of my output has `{}` around each iteration, like this:

> { John } { andrewmata361@gmail.com }

I'm not sure what is going on and why these brackets are appearing around all of my output or how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blade doesn't use curly braces for control flow. Just remove them:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->email }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to take those out. Thanks!